# Javascript canvas interactive chart - how to make my code shorter

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

I'm trying to teach myself javascript and HTML5, (just beginning), and for some practice with canvas I am trying to turn [this chart](http://www.stefan.gr/dhammachart-bigger.gif) into an interactive chart on canvas, whereby clicking on a word opens up some of the tree below, and so on. I can't post images of what it does as I'm too new here, sorry.

The thing is, the code I have done is all working as I want it to (yay!), but it's already pretty long, and to map the rest of the chart (I've only done a small part of it so far) it's going to be War and Peace in javascript. So I was wondering if anyone could take a look at my code and tell me how to make it briefer?

I've googled, and looked in my books on javascript, and nothing jumps out at me. I am also going to try and do it with SVG for practice with that, and suspect it may be more efficient, but as I specifically want to learn javascript+canvas I really want to get this way working well also. Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit to add: I tried putting functions inside functions e.g. calling BDS() where I wanted to write that out, rather than copying the code, but that simply caused it not to do any of the stuff after it.

Here is my code:

```
onload = BDS;
var called = false;

function BDS() {

var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.font = "bold 48px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#F63";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
var B = "Buddha          ";
var D = "Dhamma          ";
var S = "Sangha";
ctx.fillText(B     +     D      +    S, 500, 100);

}

function q(event) {
event = event || window.event;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
x = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft,
y = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;

//alert(x + ' ' + y);
if (x < 295 && x > 120 && y > 60 && y < 110){
    called = false;
    buddha();
}

if (x < 600 && x > 400 && y > 60 && y < 110) {
    called = true;
    dhamma();   
}

if (x < 880 && x > 710 && y > 60 && y < 110) {
    called = false;
    sangha();
}

if (called === true && x < 330 && x > 140 && y > 260 && y <300) {
    alert("yay"); 
}


}



function buddha() {
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 750);

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(185, 120);
ctx.lineTo(500, 250);
ctx.strokeStyle = "#FCF";
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.stroke();

ctx.font = "bold 48px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#F63";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
var B = "Buddha          ";
var D = "Dhamma          ";
var S = "Sangha";
ctx.fillText(B     +     D      +    S, 500, 100);

ctx.font = "bold 40px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#0C0";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("Accomplished", 500, 300);

ctx.font = "bold 40px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#0C0";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("Fully Enlightened", 500, 350);

ctx.font = "bold 40px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#0C0";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("Perfect in True Knowledge and Conduct", 500, 400);

ctx.font = "bold 40px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#0C0";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("Sublime", 500, 450);

ctx.font = "bold 40px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#0C0";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("Knower of Worlds", 500, 500);

ctx.font = "bold 40px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#0C0";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("Incomparable Leader of Persons to be Tamed", 500, 550);

ctx.font = "bold 40px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#0C0";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("Teacher of Gods and Humans", 500, 600);

ctx.font = "bold 40px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#0C0";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("Blessed", 500, 650);
}

function sangha(){
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 750);

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(800, 120);
ctx.lineTo(270, 250);
ctx.strokeStyle = "#FCF";
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.stroke();

ctx.moveTo(840, 120);
ctx.lineTo(680, 250);
ctx.strokeStyle = "#FCF";
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.stroke();

ctx.font = "bold 48px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#F63";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
var B = "Buddha          ";
var D = "Dhamma          ";
var S = "Sangha";
ctx.fillText(B     +     D      +    S, 500, 100);

ctx.font = "bold 40px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#0C0";
ctx.textAlign = "right";
ctx.fillText("Monastic Sangha     ", 500, 300);

ctx.font = "bold 36px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#FCF";
ctx.textAlign = "right";
ctx.fillText("Nuns                ", 500, 350);

ctx.font = "bold 36px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#FCF";
ctx.textAlign = "right";
ctx.fillText("Monks               ", 500, 400);

ctx.font = "bold 36px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#FCF";
ctx.textAlign = "right";
ctx.fillText("Novice Nuns         ", 500, 450);

ctx.font = "bold 36px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#FCF";
ctx.textAlign = "right";
ctx.fillText("Novice Monks        ", 500, 500);

ctx.font = "bold 40px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#0C0";
ctx.textAlign = "left";
ctx.fillText("     Noble Sangha", 500, 300);

ctx.font = "bold 36px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#FCF";
ctx.textAlign = "left";
ctx.fillText("          Arahants", 500, 350);

ctx.font = "bold 36px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#FCF";
ctx.textAlign = "left";
ctx.fillText("      Non-Returners", 500, 400);

ctx.font = "bold 36px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#FCF";
ctx.textAlign = "left";
ctx.fillText("     Once-Returners", 500, 450);

ctx.font = "bold 36px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#FCF";
ctx.textAlign = "left";
ctx.fillText("     Stream-Enterers", 500, 500);
}

function dhamma() {
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 750);

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(500, 120);
ctx.lineTo(235, 250);
ctx.strokeStyle = "#FCF";
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.stroke();

ctx.moveTo(505, 120);
ctx.lineTo(420, 250);
ctx.strokeStyle = "#FCF";
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.stroke();

ctx.moveTo(510, 120);
ctx.lineTo(620, 250);
ctx.strokeStyle = "#FCF";
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.stroke();

ctx.moveTo(515, 120);
ctx.lineTo(805, 250);
ctx.strokeStyle = "#FCF";
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.stroke();

ctx.font = "bold 48px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#F63";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
var B = "Buddha          ";
var D = "Dhamma          ";
var S = "Sangha";
ctx.fillText(B     +     D      +    S, 500, 100);

ctx.font = "bold 40px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#09F";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("Suffering    Origin    Cessation    Path", 500, 300);
}
```

Comment: I highly suggest you use a framework rather than tackling this head on with raw JS.

Answer (score 1):

[Canvas Query](http://canvasquery.com/) will be very helpful. Once you load it you will be able to chain methods as follows:

```
ctx.font = "bold 40px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#0C0";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("Fully Enlightened", 500, 350);
```

can be shortened to:

```
cq('#canvas');
cq().textAlign('center').font('bold 48px Arial').fillStyle('#F63').fillText"Fully Enlightened", 500, 350);
```

You have some other areas of improvement as well. First of all, your code will be easier to review if you fix up your indentation and make your function names more informative than `BDS` and `q`.

Now...you never call `q` in your code snippet, so it is unclear what event is the trigger...please post the full script if possible so it is more clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Anyway, you can abstract a lot of your code using the [OnceAndOnlyOnce](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?OnceAndOnlyOnce) principle. Take for example that you initialize all three functions in a similar way:

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 750);

ctx.font = "bold 48px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#F63";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
var B = "Buddha          ";
var D = "Dhamma          ";
var S = "Sangha";
ctx.fillText(B     +     D      +    S, 500, 100);
```

despite the fact that **the exact same code** is contained in your BDS method. I'm not sure why you feel it is necessary to clear the canvas after each method is called... Anyway I would rename `BDS` to `setup` and just call it from inside the `buddha`, etc. functions if you feel this clearing of the canvas is necessary. Also you are caching variables you don't reuse. You could change the above to:

```
var text = ['Buddha', 'Dhamma', 'Sangha'].join('          '); // Whitespace not preserved...
cq().textAlign('center').font('bold 48px Arial').fillStyle('#F63').fillText(text, 500, 100);
```

Another abstraction you can make is that you do something similar to the following all over your code:

```
ctx.font = "bold 40px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#0C0";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("Accomplished", 500, 300);
```

Abstract it!

```
function label(text, x, y, styleClass){
    if( typeof styleClass != 'undefined'){
        cq().textAlign(styleClass.textAlign)
            .font(styleClass.font)
            .fillStyle(styleClass.fillStyle);
        }
    cq().fillText(text, x, y);
}
```

This function can actually be further reduced to:

```
function label(text, x, y, styleClass){
    if( typeof styleClass != 'undefined'){
        cq().set(styleClass);
    }
    cq().fillText(text, x, y);
}
```

Now you can do:

```
var style1 = {font: "bold 40px Arial", textAlign: "center", fillStyle: "#0C0"};

setup();
function buddha() {
    cq().beginPath().moveTo(185, 120).lineTo(500, 250).strokeStyle("#FCF").lineWidth(5).stroke();

    label("Accomplished", 500, 300, style1);
    label("Fully Enlightened", 500, 350);
    label("Perfect in True Knowledge and Conduct", 500, 400);
    label("Sublime", 500, 450);
    label("Knower of Worlds", 500, 500);
    label("Incomparable Leader of Persons to be Tamed", 500, 550);
    label("Teacher of Gods and Humans", 500, 600);
    label("Blessed", 500, 650);
}
```

Note that you only need to pass in a style object if you are changing the style. You could perform a similar abstraction with your lines:

```
function edge(x1, y1, x2, y2, lineStyle){
    if (typeof lineStyle != 'undefined'){
        cq().set(lineStyle);
    }
    cq().beginPath().moveTo(x1, y1).lineTo(x2, y2).stroke();
}

lineStyle = {strokeStyle: "#FCF", lineWidth: 5};
edge(185, 120, 500, 250, lineStyle);
```

Now your complete code should look like:

```
onload = setup;

function setup() {
    cq('#canvas');
    var text = ['Buddha', 'Dhamma', 'Sangha'].join('          ');
    cq().textAlign('center').font('bold 48px Arial').fillStyle('#F63').fillText(text, 500, 100);
    buddha();
    dhamma();
    sangha();
}

function label(text, x, y, styleClass){
    if( typeof styleClass != 'undefined'){
        cq().textAlign(styleClass.textAlign)
            .font(styleClass.font)
            .fillStyle(styleClass.fillStyle);
        }
    cq().fillText(text, x, y);
}

function edge(x1, y1, x2, y2, lineStyle){
    if (typeof lineStyle != 'undefined'){
        cq().strokeStyle(lineStyle.strokeStyle)
            .lineWidth(lineStyle.lineWidth);
    }
    cq().beginPath().moveTo(x1, y1).lineTo(x2, y2).stroke();
}

var edgeStyle =  {strokeStyle: "#FCF", lineWidth: 5};
var labelStyles = {
    Buddha: {font: "bold 40px Arial", textAlign: "center", fillStyle: "#0C0"},
    Sangha: {font: "bold 36px Arial", textAlign: "right", fillStyle: "#FCF"},
    Dhamma: {font: "bold 40px Arial", textAlign: "center", fillStyle: "#0C0"}
};

function buddha() {
    edge(185, 120, 500, 250, edgeStyle);
    label("Accomplished", 500, 300, labelStyles.Buddha);
    label("Fully Enlightened", 500, 350);
    label("Perfect in True Knowledge and Conduct", 500, 400);
    label("Sublime", 500, 450);
    label("Knower of Worlds", 500, 500);
    label("Incomparable Leader of Persons to be Tamed", 500, 550);
    label("Teacher of Gods and Humans", 500, 600);
    label("Blessed", 500, 650);
}

function sangha(){
    edge(800, 120, 270, 250, edgeStyle);
    edge(840, 120, 680, 250);
    label("Monastic Sangha     ", 500, 300, labelStyles.Sangha);
    label("Nuns                ", 500, 350);
    label("Monks               ", 500, 400);
    label("Novice Nuns         ", 500, 450);
    label("     Noble Sangha", 500, 300);
    label("          Arahants", 500, 350);
    label("      Non-Returners", 500, 400);
    label("     Once-Returners", 500, 450);
    label("     Stream-Enterers", 500, 500);
}

function dhamma() {
    edge(500, 120, 235, 250, edgeStyle);
    edge(505, 120, 420, 250);
    edge(510, 120, 620, 250);
    edge(515, 120, 805, 250);
    label("Suffering    Origin    Cessation    Path", 500, 300);
}
```

You just trimmed your code from 231 lines down to 69!

Comment: Thank you! The function q() is called in the html to make the mouseclick thing work: onclick=q(event). The indentation is less of a mess in ecplise than it looks in my post. I'll go back now and make my names make more sense, and start condensing stuff like you've suggested. Many many thanks for taking the time to go through it so thoroughly :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem as well. I like to keep my code short and clean. If I don't, I usually end of abandoning a project because it gets too long and messy.
What I do is condense actions that are carried out many times on the canvas.

Example:

```
// drawing a bunch of rectangles to canvas the old way.

canvas.save();
canvas.fillStyle = "red";
canvas.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
canvas.restore();
canvas.save();
canvas.fillStyle = "blue";
canvas.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
canvas.restore();
// etc....

//instead create a function for making simple rectangles

function drawRect(x, y, width, height, color) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.fillStyle = color;
    canvas.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    canvas.restore();
};

//now i can call this function whenever i need a rectangle
//also you can use rgb(red, green, blue) in place of named colors.

drawRect(0, 0, 50, 60, "yellow");
drawRect(50, 50, 100, 200, "red");
drawRect(0, 50, 200, 300, rgb(120, 40, 200));
```